# R Server / SQL Server Data Import - How to Import Dates in Appropriate Format?

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I am trying to Import a SQL Server Data table into R Server. The data table in SQL Server has datetimes formatted as datetime, but when I use the following code the tables do not come into R in appropriate format.

```
`xxx<- RxSqlServerData(table = "vwTCMSDataGPC",
                                    connectionString = connStr,
                                    colClasses = col)`
```

I can use `rxGetVarInfo(xxx)` to show that the table imports the datetime files as character classes. This means I have to run this code to get my dates in appropriate format

```
xxx<- rxDataStep(inData = xxx,
                    transforms = list(BeginTime = as.POSIXct(BeginTime),
                                      RestoreTime = as.POSIXct(RestoreTime),
                                      ERTGeneratedTime = as.POSIXct(ERTGeneratedTime)),
                    maxRowsByCols = 1000000000)
```

Due to the size of my data this take 30-40 minutes. Thats 10% of my workday gone each time I have to run this. I would like to be able to simply put `BeginTime = "POSIXct"` etc in my object named `col` used in the `RxSqlServerData` step, but that doesn't work and you get an error that suggests converting to POSIXct the way I did.

I want it to simply import my sql server data as an object with appropriate formats when I run rxGetVarInfo that way I do not have to spend 10% of my day formatting a file. Also, this is important for when this solution gets put into production. There is not time to do this tedious step.

How do I make this work how I would like it to work?

Answer (score 0):

ODBC does not support the datetime conversion at this point.

Here are some solutions:

1. Datatime can be converted to POSIX correctly in T-SQL as shown in this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-r-and-sql-data-types-and-data-objects#cast-or-convert-sql-server-data
2. The slow processing time the post’s author encountered seems to be because of the inefficiency of as.POSIXct(), as the example below shows, specifying the datetime format before hand or use the lubridate package greatly improves the efficiency.

> df=rxImport(dt, transforms =list(dt2=as.POSIXct(dt1)))

Rows Read: 1000000, Total Rows Processed: 1000000, Total Chunk Time: 34.223 seconds

> df=rxImport(dt, transforms =list(dt2=as.POSIXct(dt1, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

Rows Read: 1000000, Total Rows Processed: 1000000, Total Chunk Time: 18.733 seconds

> df=rxImport(dt, transforms =list(dt2=lubridate::ydm_hms(dt1)))

Rows Read: 1000000, Total Rows Processed: 1000000, Total Chunk Time: 3.319 seconds